# Mass assignment  in rails3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Im working on a simple rails project were users have an attribute called is_admin, and the is_admin cannot be assigned through mass asignment(atr_assecsible). The problem here is, i want to create a default user with the value is_admin => true and i do not no if it would be possible from the migration file because of the protected attribute(:is_admin). so that wen i run rake rails:setup it creates the migrations and the default admin user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, migrations don't use mass assignment. I don't see why you would have an issue doing this.

Comment: Thanks just wanted to be sure before trying.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a recent Rails version:

```
MyModel.create({my_attr: 1, is_admin: true}, without_protection: true)}
```

or you can look into the as: option

```
attr_accessible :is_admin, as: :admin
MyModel.create({my_attr: 1, is_admin: true}, as: :admin)}
```

Comment: your second line of code is it in the migration file and pls what is the my_attr: 1 you are passing

Comment: I suggest using the task rake db:seed and edit your seeds.rb file to create default objects anyway.

The my_attr is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, without_protection parameter works only on Rails 3.1